# Match string using regular expression except specific string combinations python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, regex-negation

In a list I need to match specific instances, except for a specific combination  of strings:

let's say I have a list of strings like the following:

```
l = [
'PSSTFRPPLYO',
'BNTETNTT',
'DE52 5055 0020 0005 9287 29',
'210-0601001-41',
'BSABESBBXXX',
'COMMERZBANK'
]
```

I need to match all the words that points to a [swift / bic code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9362), this code has the following form:
6 letters followed by
2 letters/digits followed by
3 optional letters / digits

hence I have written the following regex to match such specific pattern

```
import re
regex = re.compile(r'(?<!\w)[a-zA-Z]{6}[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}([a-zA-Z0-9]{3})?(?!\w)')
for item in l:
    match = regex.search(item)
    if match:
        print('found a match, the matched string {} the match {}'.format( item, item[match.start() : match.end()]
    else:
        print('found no match in {}'.format(item)
```

I need the following cases to be macthed:

```
result = ['PSSTFRPPLYO', 'BNTETNTT', 'BSABESBBXXX' ]
```

rather I get

```
result = ['PSSTFRPPLYO', 'BNTETNTT', 'BSABESBBXXX', 'COMMERZBANK' ]
```

so what I need is to match only the strings that don't contain the word 'bank'

to do so I have refined my regex to :

```
regex = re.compile((?<!bank/i)(?<!\w)[a-zA-Z]{6}[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}([a-zA-Z0-9]{3})?(?!\w)(?!bank/i))
```

simply I have used negative look behind and ahead for more information about theses two concepts refer to [link](https://github.com/ponach/learn-regex)

My regex doesn't do the filtration intended to do, what did I miss?

Comment: `(?!.*bank.*)^[a-z]{6}(?:[a-z0-9]{2})(?:[a-z0-9]{3})?$` with `i` modifier?

Comment: @ctwheels that's a nice trick thanks a lot.

Comment: My previous regex can actually be shortened to `(?!.*bank.*)^[a-z]{6}(?:[a-z0-9]{2}|[a-z0-9]{5})$` (4 less characters and 2 less steps) or `(?![a-z0-9]*bank[a-z0-9]*)^[a-z]{6}(?:[a-z0-9]{2}|[a-z0-9]{5})$` (more characters, but almost 400 less steps)

Comment: @ctwheels What did you use to analyze the number of steps?

Comment: @Harvey I was about to ask the same question

Comment: [regex101](https://regex101.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
import re
final_vals = [i for i in l if re.findall('^[a-zA-Z]{6}\w{2}|(^[a-zA-Z]{6}\w{2}\w{3})', i) and not re.findall('BANK', i, re.IGNORECASE)]
```

Output:

```
['PSSTFRPPLYO', 'BNTETNTT', 'BSABESBBXXX']
```

Comment: Is there no way to include the condition in the regex? instead of traversion the string twice, don't get me wrong your solution does the job, thanks a lot.